# JSF commandButton on error page in Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, jsf-2.2

Using JSF2.2 I try to use a h:commandButton on a 404 error page. Since it is the error page of the application, the POST action is not routed to the backing bean. Tomcat just returns the 404.

In my 404.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="myform">
    <h:commandButton action="#{backingBean.execute}" value="buttontext" />
</h:form>
```

My backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean{
    public String execute() {
        doSomething();
        return "newTargetPage";
    }
}
```

In my web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Calling the URL http:://localhost/myapp/invalidurl I get the following html code:

```
<form id="myform" action="/myapp/invalidurl " method="post">
    <input id="myform:execute" name="myform:execute"
           type="submit" value="buttontext" /> 
</form>
```

Since the target of the post points to an non existent page, tomcat redirects me to the 404 page and forgets the actual post action.

If I transfer all the code to a normal page it works.

Is it possible to tell JSF the target page of a form?
Is it possible to call an action using a h:button?

Comment: I don't understand your question: You request an invalid URL and get the error page that you configured. What's the problem?

Comment: @kolossus Thats fine. But on my error page I want to have a button that triggers a method of the BackingBean. If I press my h:commandButton I just recieve the 404 and my method is not executed. This happens since my action points to an invalid url.